# JSF migration on WAS 8.5 causes "The import com.ibm.faces cannot be resolved"

Tags: jsf-2, migration, websphere-8, ibm-jsf

I am migrating an old JSF application from WAS 6.x to WAS 8.x and I am getting the following compilation error:

> The import com.ibm.faces cannot be resolved

This comes from the following code:

```
import com.ibm.faces.component.html.HtmlScriptCollector;
...
protected HtmlScriptCollector onLoadCollector;
```

How do I port this for use on WAS 8.x?

Answer (score 0):

Looks so far like these methods can just be removed. A better explanation will get the check.